# jQuery glitched lightbox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a jQuery plugin called fancybox for a website I'm doing. It seems to be glitched as there is some sort of overlay at the top page which is invisible, but it activates the thumbnail view at the bottom of my page, and covers up my links and just ruins the whole page.

Website in question:
http://johns-webdesign.com/client/Andy/gallery.html

HTML

```
<div id="content" style="height:350px">
        <h1>Our Work</h1>

<div class="photo_thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/work/construction bathroom.jpg" width="160" height="100"></a><p>Title</p>
<div class="overlay"><a class="fancybox" href="img/work/construction bathroom.jpg" title="Test">Hi</a></div></div>

<div class="photo_thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/work/construction best windows.jpg" width="160" height="100"></a><p>Title</p>
<div class="overlay"><a class="fancybox" href="img/work/construction best windows.jpg" title="Test">Hi</a></div></div>

<div class="photo_thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/work/construction block.jpg" width="160" height="100"></a><p>Title</p>
<div class="overlay"><a class="fancybox" href="img/work/construction block.jpg" title="Test">Hi</a></div></div>

<div class="photo_thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/work/construction floors.jpg" width="160" height="100"></a><p>Title</p>
<div class="overlay"><a class="fancybox" href="img/work/construction floors.jpg" title="Test">Hi</a></div></div>

<div class="photo_thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/work/construction hygiene.jpg" width="160" height="100"></a><p>Title</p>
<div class="overlay"><a class="fancybox" href="img/work/construction hygiene.jpg" title="Test">Hi</a></div></div>

<div class="photo_thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/work/construction sanity.jpg" width="160" height="100"></a><p>Title</p>
<div class="overlay"><a class="fancybox" href="img/work/construction sanity.jpg" title="Test">Hi</a></div></div>

<div class="photo_thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/work/construction stair railings.jpg" width="160" height="100"></a><p>Title</p>
<div class="overlay"><a class="fancybox" href="img/work/construction stair railings.jpg" title="Test">Hi</a></div></div>

<div class="photo_thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/work/constructions stairs railings.jpg" width="160" height="100"></a><p>Title</p>
<div class="overlay"><a class="fancybox" href="img/work/constructions stairs railings.jpg" title="Test">Hi</a></div></div>


        </div>
```

CSS

```
.photo_thumb {
    height:100px;
    width:160px;
    float:left;
    margin:4px 4px 15px 4px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#999;
}
.overlay {
    height:100px;
    width:160px;
    display:none;
    margin-top:-137px;  
    background-color:#666;
    opacity:0.5;
    background-position:center;
    background-image:url(../img/zoom.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 1 0;
}
.photo_thumb:hover > .overlay {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    display:block;
    opacity:0.6;
    background-position:center; 
    background-color:#666;
    height:100px;
    width:160px;
    opacity:0.5; 
}
.photo_thumb p {
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
.overlay a{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    text-decoration:none; /* Makes sure the link   doesn't get underlined */
    z-index:10; /* raises anchor tag above everything else in div */
    background-color:white; /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    opacity: 0; /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    filter: alpha(opacity=1); /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
}
.fancybox {
    display:none;
}
```

I currently have the fancybox's display set as none as it isn't working acceptably. Here are some of the things I have gone over;

```
.overlay > .fancybox {
display:block;
}
```

This didn't fix the issue, so I tried some JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.overlay').hover(function() {
    $('.fancybox').toggle(show)();
});
    </script>
```

This didn't do a thing for some reason.

I'm stumped to be quite honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.overlay').hover(function() {
    $('.fancybox').toggle()();
    });
});
</script>
```

Fixed the issue. Thanks to the person who commented but then deleted his post, it fixed the issue but I just had to remove the attribute hide from the toggle()